# How to deactivate feature from site collecion programmatically?

Tags: feature

How to deactivate feature from site collection? I am trying the code below but got this error:

> Updates are currently disallowed on GET requests.  To allow updates on
>   a GET, set the 'AllowUnsafeUpdates' property on SPWeb".

```
private void DeactivateProvisioningFeature()
        {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                    var feature = site.Features.SingleOrDefault(sf => sf.DefinitionId == new Guid("464b78de-c14e-4c88-bd52-00136fc899f4")); // find delegate control provisioning feature
                    if (feature != null) //if feature is activated
                    {
                        site.Features.Remove(feature.DefinitionId, true); //deactivate feature
                    }

                    web.Update();

                    site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What if you bring back SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges?

Comment: Is it realy needed to use the runwithelevatedpriveleges to deactivate a site collection feature?

Comment: did you try  web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;  Web.Update();

Comment: Waqas, please see my code above. They were already available.

Comment: If you don't call Update, you are just setting a boolean that never gets applied to the site or web.

Comment: @PirateEric: there is already an web.Update(). Do I need to move it before I remove the feature from the site collection?

Comment: @PirateEric, you don't need to call an Update() after setting AllowUnsafeUpdates if you set it back again after doing the update.

Comment: so whats wrong with my code above?

Comment: did you try the update after true, what are the result?

Answer (score 0):

You do NOT need and you should NOT call `web.update()`. This mean that you save this property to the database.

To disable site collection feature, you do not need SPWeb instance also.

If you have permissions to manage features of the site, you also do not need new SPSite object instance.

Try to write you code like, this:

```
if (SPContext.Current.Site != null)
{
    site = SPContext.Current.Site;
    site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

    //YOUR FEATURE DEACTIVATION CODE

    site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
}
```